# HTML list being broken up on mobile view

Tags: html, css, list

On mobile view, my list view for 'Interests' on my resume keeps getting broken up and placed under the 'Skills' column, not to the left of the 'Interests'. I'm wondering if this has something to do with the container size or media min-width?

[Here's a web link to the resume](https://codepen.io/cjgetty/pen/yLYWwpQ). You can see the affected list towards the bottom of the page.

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/cjgetty/pen/yLYWwpQ) containing the code.

Thank you.

```css
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #262626;
  line-height: 32px;
}

header {
  color: #fff;
  background: #477987;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

p {
  color: #3F3F3F;
  font-size: 18px;
}

a {
  color: #477987;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.50;
}

.blue-link {
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  color: #477987;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #477987;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 28px;
}

.rule {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 1px;
  background: #477987;
}

h3 {
  color: #3F3F3F;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.contact {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60%;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.of {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: italic;
}

h4 {
  color: #3F3F3F;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h4 ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h3, h4 {
  line-height: 28px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #477987;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

footer {
  background: #477987;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

footer h3 {
  color: #FFF;
}

footer h4 {
  color: #EEE;
}

@media (min-width: 645px) {

  body, h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  header {
    padding: 30px 0;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    font-size: 32px;
  }

  .container {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  h5 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  h3, h4 {
    font-size: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  h4 ul {
    margin-right: 48px;
  }

  h4 li {
    padding: 0 0 12px 0;
  }

  footer {
    padding: 30px 0 40px;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 820px) {

  .container {
    width: 820px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Cameron Getty | Resume</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="name">Cameron Getty</h2>
      <h3 class="contact"><a class="blue-link" href="mailto:cameronjgetty@gmail.com">cameronjgetty@gmail.com</a></h3>
      <h3 class="contact">209.981.8269</h3>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Experience</h2>
    <div class="rule"></div>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Photography Lab & Studio Assistant</h3>
      <h4> &#8226; CSU Sacramento</h4>
      <p>&bull; Provided technical demonstrations for students and assisted with any troubleshooting.</p>
      <p>&bull; Maintained studio and darkroom operations, including but not limited to: setup and teardown of photographic chemicals, studio lighting, and darkroom enlargers; daily cleaning of equipment and work areas.
      <h5>August 2019—May 2020&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sacramento, CA
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h3>Graphic Design Intern</h3>
      <h4> &#8226; Lunia Blue Graphics, Inc.</h4>
      <p>&bull; Aided in the conceptualization, design, and execution of new online and print campaigns for regionally-based startups to national brands.</p>
      <p>&bull; Organized and maintained in-house server and client assets.</p>
      <h5>August 2018—May 2019&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sacramento, CA
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h3>Communications Intern</h3>
      <h4> &#8226; California Conservation Corps</h4>
      <p>&bull; Drafted and managed online, print, and social media communications designed to promote company brand, mission, and values.</p>
      <p>&bull; Assisted in the management and implementation of digital assets and website content.</p>
      <h5>May 2017—February 2018&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sacramento, CA
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h3>Technical Support Advisor</h3>
      <h4> &#8226; Apple, Inc.</h4>
      <p>&bull; Provided exceptional technical phone support for iOS products (iPhone, iPad, etc.) for AppleCare customers.</p>
      <p>&bull; Managed a wide variety of customer service and administrative tasks to resolve customer issues quickly and efficiently.</p>
      <p>&bull; Self-managed and worked independently in a fast-paced, constantly changing environment.</p>
      <h5>September 2016—April 2017&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sacramento, CA
    </div>

    <h2>Education</h2>
      <div class="rule"></div>
      <div class="item">
        <h3>Bachelor <span class="of">of</span> Arts&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>
        <h4>Photography</h4>
        <h5>California State University, Sacramento</h5>
      </div>

    <h2>Projects</h2>
    <div class="rule"></div>
    <div class="item">
      <h3><a href="http://quaranzines.cargo.site">Quaranzines</a></h3>
      <h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;CSU Sacramento</h4>
      <p>Quaranzines is a collaborative, online zine festival created by CSU Sacramento students and professors. I served as the website designer and digital asset manager for the project.</p>
      <h5>Web designer and digital asset manager</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h3><a href="https://github.com/cjgetty/pixeltools">Pixel Tools</a></h3>
      <h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;Personal</h4>
      <p>Pixel Tools is a free, open-source resource library for designers and creative teams.
</p>
      <h5>Designer & coder</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <h3><a href="https://www.placeholdermag.com/index.html">Placeholder Magazine</a></h3>
      <p>Placeholder Magazine is a fiercely independent critical voice covering contemporary arts, culture, and literature in the Central Valley of California, led entirely by volunteers. I acted as assistant web designer and freelance contributor.</p>
      <h5>Assistant web designer and freelance contributor</h5>
    </div>

    <h2>Skills & Interests</h2>
    <div class="rule"></div>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Skills&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>
      <h4>
        <ul>
          <li>HTML/CSS</li>
          <li>Customer Servive</li>
          <li>Asana, Microsoft Teams, Slack, etc.</li>
          <li>Adobe Creative Suite</li>
          <li>Ability to Work Independently</li>
          <li>Microsoft Office</li>
          <li>Content Management Systems</li>
        </ul>
      </h4>

      <h3>Interests&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>
      <h4>
        <ul>
          <li>Collecting records </li>
          <li>Film photography </li>
          <li>Art history </li>
          <li>Helping people ‍</li>
        </ul>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>

    <footer>
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Get in touch?</h3>
        <h4><a class="blue-link" href="mailto:cameronjgetty@gmail.com">cameronjgetty@gmail.com</a> / 209.981.8269</h4>
      </div>
    </footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this css :

```
@media (min-width: 645px){

h4 ul {
    margin-right: 48px;
}
}
```

in screenshot is shown changes
[image: screeshot]

Answer (score 0):

There are many markup validation issues in your HTML. To solve this problem you just fix those problems. You may follow my `codepen` [link](https://codepen.io/rajibmehedihasan/pen/VwvOROp).